# Remember users email id after logout - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Condition:
If user is inactive for certain period eg. (2 mins) it automatically gets logout but his user email id will still be pre-filled.

But in laravel on logout all session is flushed. How to achieve that in laravel?

Comment: Why not just store user's email in a cookie when they log in and use its value to pre-fill the email?

Comment: Store the email in cookie, or put it in the indexed DB of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you've seen that before, just remember that has nothing to do with the application.

Your browser remembers the fields you previously entered on that page if it is configured to.

What you're asking can be attempted by saving the IP against a user and use that to pre-fill the username field. But of course, a user could access the site from a different IP.

This is also dangerous territory. Consider a public computer being used to access the app. Do you want just anyone to be able to see your username? Of course not. There are other considerations too.

Long story short, don't do it.

*PS : Please visit [GDPR](https://termsfeed.com/blog/gdpr-privacy-policy/) link once before doing.*

Comment: no this is an intranet product.. So dont worry about the public computer. Even facebook uses such remember username... So its not dangerous until one knows its password.